# conflict in Lightbox and Easing Slider

Tags: css, lightbox

I am facing conflict issues in both functionalities. If I use the **//for slider** code above then, lightbox works and easyslider wont work and vice-versa. What is the solution to get it done ?

I am using following code in the header

```
//for lightbox
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>


//for slider
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: true, 
            continuous: true,
            numeric: true
        });
    }); 
</script>
```